# How to move the field error element ".Mage-error" outside of the ".field" element? Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, javascript, xml, custom-field

I am new to Magento, and am using Magento 2.2.

How can we move the error message that is generated to the outside of it's field parent.
Please note that I am looking for a way to do it through my custom theme.
Please see the screenshot for clarification.

[image: Moving error outside of it's parent field element]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to do this. I am sharing the answer to my question in case someone needs to do this:

1. Create a folder called `mage` in your custom template with the following path:

`/Sample/CustomTemplate/web/mage`

2. Place a copy of the file `validation.js` in this new mage folder. You can find a copy of the original `validation.js` in the following path:

`/Magento Folder/lib/web/validation.js`

3. In my case, I wanted to move the `.mage-error` outside of the `.field` element, so I replace the following code:

   ```
   fieldWrapper = element.closest('.addon');
   ```

   with

   ```
   fieldWrapper = element.closest('.field');
   ```